# Extract specific row from clipboard with AppleScript

Tags: macos, applescript, automator

I'm using the following code to get the content of my clipboard into my Automator code:

```
set theString to get the clipboard
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, ";"}
set theList to text items of theString
set text item delimiters to TID
```

However, if the user has copied the following lines:

```
word1;word2;word3
word4;word5;word6
```

How do I extract the second row only? I'm not interested in the first row, and the number of columns can change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* works for me:

```applescript
set myTextItemDelimiter to ";"

if (clipboard info for string) is {} then
    display dialog ¬
        "The clipboard does not contain text." buttons {"OK"} ¬
        default button 1 giving up after 5
    return
end if

set theString to (the clipboard) as string

if theString does not contain myTextItemDelimiter then
    display dialog ¬
        "The clipboard does not contain the \"" & ¬
        myTextItemDelimiter & "\" delimiter." buttons {"OK"} ¬
        default button 1 giving up after 5
    return
end if

if (count paragraphs of theString) is greater than 1 then
    set theString to paragraph 2 of theString
else
    display dialog ¬
        "The clipboard only contains one line of text." buttons {"OK"} ¬
        default button 1 giving up after 5
    return
end if

set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, myTextItemDelimiter}
set theList to text items of theString
set text item delimiters to TID

return theList
```

---

**Notes:**

I added some *error handling* to the *code*.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
set the clipboard to "word1;word2;word3
word4;word5;word6"

set theClipboard to (the clipboard)

set secondLine to (paragraph 2 of theClipboard)

set theString to secondLine
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, ";"}
set theList to text items of theString
set text item delimiters to TID
```

**OR**

```
set the clipboard to "word1;word2;word3
word4;word5;word6"

set secondLine to paragraph 2 of (the clipboard)

set theString to secondLine
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, ";"}
set theList to text items of theString
set text item delimiters to TID
```

**OR**

```
set the clipboard to "word1;word2;word3
word4;word5;word6"

set theString to paragraph 2 of (the clipboard)
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, ";"}
set theList to text items of theString
set text item delimiters to TID
```